# CSS - transform: scale() irrespective of element size

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is there a way to apply a `transform: scale()` to an element (or something similar, although ideally it should be able to be safely animated) which would make the element appear larger, however "ignore" the element's size (obviously this isn't exactly what I mean, keep reading).

[Here](https://codepen.io/devmattrick/pen/pqoOLb) is an example of what I mean.

Essentially the idea is to make the 2 differently size elements *appear* to scale in the same way, despite being 2 different sizes. It should be noted that the elements aren't going to be fixed width and will inherit the size of their container (whose width is also indeterminate).

Comment: Please go through this https://codepen.io/edwardpayton/pen/pjyogj?editors=1010

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara thanks for the response, however I'd like to avoid using JS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Thanks @TemaniAfif, the solution can be optimized further by manipulating the left and right margin instead of width.

```css
.small {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.large {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.target {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.target:hover {
  margin: 0 -12px;
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, margin 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <div class="target">Small</div>
</div>
<div class="large">
  <div class="target">Large</div>
</div>
```

### Original Answer

The `scale` function resizes the element by multiplication, but you need a constant enlargement on the variant x-axis. Instead use `scale`, using `calc` on width of a proxy element (.target) to add the constant pixel when the element needs to be enlarged. By enlarging width, the position of the element also needs an offset to make it grows to left, so set the `left` to a negative number which is a half of the total enlargement. Since heights of the two elements are the same, using `scaleY` to scale them is ok.

```css
.small {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

.large {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.target {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.target:hover {
  left: -12px;
  width: calc(100% + 24px);
  transform: scaleY(1.2);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, left 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <div class="target">Small</div>
</div>
<div class="large">
  <div class="target">Large</div>
</div>
```

Comment: probably explain your approach

Comment: you can make easier and instead of changing width your rely on left/right .. you start with 0 at both then -12xp at both

Comment: @TemaniAfif interesting, but it doesn't work, the right side won't grow..

Comment: you should remove the width completely, even from the non hover state and it will work

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://codepen.io/floydwch/pen/pqoGEr the second group implements what you suggest, but the right side still does not work..

Comment: ah it's because of the relative position, I thought we are dealing with absolute position. In this case, yes it won't work because the width won't be defined with right/left ... in this case you can then use -12px with margin-right/left and it will work